# Visual Studio Code fails to open from Powershell

Tags: powershell, visual-studio-code

I'm trying to open Visual Studio Code from Powershell using the `code` command while inside a folder. When I try to do this, I always get this error:

> Blockquote code : The term 'code' is not recognized as the name of a cmdlet, function, script file, or operable program.
>   Check the spelling of the name, or if a path was included, verify that the path is correct and try again.
>   At line:1 char:1
>   + code .
>   + ~~~~
>   + CategoryInfo          : ObjectNotFound: (code:String) [], CommandNotFoundException
>   + FullyQualifiedErrorId : CommandNotFoundException

Comment: As the error message says: The command `code` is not recognized. The command needs to be in a directory in your `Path` environment variable.

Comment: Yeah even when i use the correct Path it wont open in VS code, even if i just want to open vs code (the program and not a project) i get this error

Comment: @Bill_Stewart I thought it was that problem too but I made some research and I found this closed issue: https://github.com/Microsoft/vscode/issues/22881. I think you (@Horbachus) can find your solution here.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

When you install Visual Studio Code, there is a checkbox in the installer labeled:

> Add to PATH (requires shell restart)

[image: installer image]

Make sure this is checked, and that you restart any active shell instances after installation is completed.

Answer (score 4):

I found a closed GitHub issue (https://github.com/Microsoft/vscode/issues/22881) with the exact same problem and the solution for the person who asked for a solution was:

```
Go to File > Preferences > Settings

Change the property "terminal.integrated.shell.windows" as follows:
      "terminal.integrated.shell.windows": "C:\Windows\System32\cmd.exe"

Restart visual studio.
```

Comment: This tells VSCode to use the old Windows batch cmd, instead of PowerShell. I think you're supposed to put the path to the pwsh.exe there.