# Not able to install twilio in visual studio code

Tags: python, twilio

Error while running `pip install twilio` 
Error:

```
pip : The term 'pip' is not recognized as the name of a cmdlet, function, script file, or operable program. Check the 
    spelling of the name, or if a path was included, verify that the path is correct and try again.
```

At line:1 char:1

- pip install twilio
- ```
    + CategoryInfo          : ObjectNotFound: (pip:String) [], CommandNotFoundException        
    + FullyQualifiedErrorId : CommandNotFoundException
  ```

Comment: Check [this](https://stackoverflow.com/a/59162251). It seems your problem is similar and can be solved the same way

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Visual Studio Code fails to open from Powershell](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/59162082/visual-studio-code-fails-to-open-from-powershell)