# g++ is recognized by cmd but not by vs code

Tags: c++, visual-studio-code, mingw

I'm trying to set c/c++ environment in my visual studio code. I have installed the mingw and set the environmental variable of the bin folder. However upon running a code in vs code, it shows the following error:

> g++ : The term 'g++' is not recognized as the name of a cmdlet, function,  script file, or operable program. Check the spelling of the
> name, or if a path   was included, verify that the path is correct and
> try again. At line:1 char:40
> cd "e:\vsCodes\Cpp Codes" ; if ($?) { g++ threen1.cpp -o threen1 } ; ...
> CategoryInfo          : ObjectNotFound: (g++:String) [], CommandNotFound      Exception
> FullyQualifiedErrorId : CommandNotFoundException

But command prompt shows the following message when I enter `g++ --version`:

> g++ (tdm64-1) 10.3.0 Copyright (C) 2020 Free Software Foundation, Inc.
> This is free software; see the source for copying conditions.  There
> is NO warranty; not even for MERCHANTABILITY or FITNESS FOR A
> PARTICULAR PURPOSE.

I have tried solving the issue following the answers in [this thread](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/59162082/visual-studio-code-fails-to-open-from-powershell).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You are using `powershell` terminal, If you dont know what powershell is or you dont need powershell, I recommend you to run Command prompt terminal (cmd). It's available in terminal menu here:

[image]

In powershell you can verify that `g++` in `PATH` running this command `echo $env:path`, it's powershell equivalent of `echo %PATH%`